# Rails: Using custom classes in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I want to pass an array of custom objects to the view layer to render. Rails [expects to be able to call "model_name"](http://log.demaree.me/post/337554241/rails-model-names) and a bunch of other methods for routing on its models.

If I want to make a custom class that I can pass to methods like "render", what methods does it need to respond to?

Ideally I would like these objects to be usable outside rails as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using Rails 3 then it might be worth extending `ActiveModel`.

See these posts for more info:

- [ActiveModel: Make Any Ruby Object Feel Like ActiveRecord](http://yehudakatz.com/2010/01/10/activemodel-make-any-ruby-object-feel-like-activerecord/)
- [Rails 3.0′s ActiveModel: How To Give Ruby Classes Some ActiveRecord Magic](http://www.rubyinside.com/rails-3-0s-activemodel-how-to-give-ruby-classes-some-activerecord-magic-2937.html)

Comment: Following the instructions in the second link and adding a "name" method to the class did the trick. Thanks!